# android studio thread execution

Tags: android, multithreading, queue

I've got a thread in a for loop to download some files from a http server reading the file names in an array list.
I need to launch several times the thread to get all the files, it seems that some threads don't achieve but with no rules at all.
I would like to launch the threads in order to see if each task works fine and optionally do something if not.
here's my code

```
for(String object:stringArrayList_dwlfromex){
                   try {
                       //String result = stringArrayList_dwlfromex.get(k);
                       String result = String.valueOf(object);
                       String[]row=result.split(";");
                       imei = row[4].toString();
                       dir = row[1].toString();
                       filename = row[2].toString();
                       compteur++;
                       //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),dir+"&"+filename,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),compteur+"  "+result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       new Thread(new Runnable() {

                           public void run() {

                               DownloadFiles(imei,dir,filename);
                           }
                       }).start();
                   }catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
```

any idea?

Comment: What is DownloadFIles? Is it a function? If so, it should be downloadFiles(). Also, can you provide the code of downloadFiles()? And I know this doesn't address your question specificaly, but have you tried using Retrofit?

Comment: I'm using okhttp. Downloadfiles is a function. I'm gonna change it but it already works.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please post the solution for future reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I never see any workaround like you did.

You will have to make a [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) with [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask). You will not use for loop.

Solution is to download another file when one is downloaded. You have to set a interface callback when a file is downloaded. and execute next download after this. Also destroy service when executed files size is equal to your list.

Comment: Thanks Khemraj for your response. I'm using an asynctask to request the filenames to download or upload to the server. the code I posted is in the postexecute.Can I use another one within it?Could you tell me more about the interface settings?